Is Certificate Signing Request (CSR) only generated once?
I have server in my office that currently cannot be accessed due to expired SSL certificate. The system administrator wanted me to give them CSR file and private key.
My question is could i send them CSR that i generated 2 years ago or do i have to generate new?
and do private key is important for them? As i know, private key must be keep privately.
Thanks in advance.

Generally spoken, a private key file should never leave the machine it has been generated on. The private key / certificate mechanism was invented in a way which makes this possible.

The private key file is only needed on the webserver for which the certificate is supposed to be issued for - so that is the place where you should generate the key...
The CA issuing the certificate only needs the CSR.

Now, you write "system administrator". If he is the guy who has to install the certificate on the webserver, then yes - he needs the private key. But then again, if he is the guy with access to the webserver, why is he not the one generating the private key and CSR directly on the webserver?
Concerning your second question: As far as I know, it should be possible to reuse the CSR from two years ago - as long as you still have the private key file for it, and you can be certain that the private key has not been disclosed. But you do not have any benefit from reusing that CSR, so you just might as well generate a new key and a new CSR - that way, you can be sure that your private key has not been compromised.

There are plenty of organizations that perform a request/renewal on a host that is different from where a certificate is deployed. There isn't anything fundamentally insecure with it. If you look at large web presences the workflows for certificate automation may not include local CSR generation at all.

Yes I know, and those organizations have very good reasons to do so - but this doesn't make my statement incorrect, as this is supposed to be a general advice.
